# Embedding JWT user tokens to Kafka events so that consuming apps can act on behalf of this user

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, architecture, jwt

I have a scenario where an user can perform an action, which results in an event published in Kafka. This event is consumed by many applications, each of which needs to perform some action for this user. The way it works now is that the events contain the user identifier, and the services trust each other and can perform actions for arbitrary users.

We are planning to attach the user token (JWT) to the event which would allow the service to attach that token for any other call it needs to make after it consumes the event. This makes the user identifier implicit. Is this a common practice to do it this way? Is there an established mechanism that gives us more security (embedding high-confidence tokens with long lifespan might not be a great idea)?

Comment: I think that we may be putting already expired tokens into the events so that the services could check whether the token was valid at that time in the past. This way no future actions can happen and we only ever perform actions which are the consequence of some historic actions taken by the user.